# Is it possible to turn an array into a list of parameters for a function?

Tags: elixir

I have a function that accepts `n` number of parameters (it's the devinus/sh function) where you can execute a command line program and obtain the results:

Example: `Sh.file "-b", "--mime-type", path_to_file`

But I want to have the parameters in an array so they can be varying depending on how the function is called.

Example of what I want:

```
data = ["-b", "--mime-type", path_to_file]

# a way of going through the array and turning it into the parameters for the Sh function

Sh.file <loop array params here>
```

Sh doesn't take an array for a parameter.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `apply(Sh, :file, args)`, where `args` is an array of arguments.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for that, I wasn't aware of the apply function :)